# Get sex from table then groupby to current date filter with academic level

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-api

Im quite new with laravel relationship and eloquent. I want to count total enrolled students in todays date and groupby sex & academic level.

Here's my api.

```
Route::get('/count-student-enrollment-by-sex-and-academic-level', [EnrollmentController::class, 'countStudentEnrollmentBySexAndAcademicLevel']);
```

Here's my enrollment model.

```
class Enrollment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'enrollment';
    protected $fillable = [
        'session_id',
        'student_id',
        'program_id',
        'academic_level_id',
    ];

    public function session()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Session', 'session_id');
    }

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Student', 'student_id');
    }

    public function program()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Program', 'program_id');
    }

    public function academicLevel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AcademicLevel', 'academic_level_id');
    }
}
```

**Relationships**

Session, student, program, academic level `hasMany` relationship with enrollment.

Here's my academic level table

```
protected $table = 'academic_levels';
    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'name',
        'description',
        'ordering',
    ];
```

Here's illustration to what i want to achieve.
[image]

Edit:

What I tried in controller:

```
public function countStudentEnrollmentBySexAndAcademicLevel(){         
    $users = array_reduce(Student::select('sex', 
        DB::raw('count(*) as count'))->groupBy('sex')->get()
        ->toArray(), function ($carry, $data) {             
            $carry[$data['sex']] = $data['count'];             
            return $carry;         
        });         
    return response()->json($users, 200);     
}
```

Comment: what you tried in `controller`?

Comment: ```public function countStudentEnrollmentBySexAndAcademicLevel()
    {
        $users = array_reduce(Student::select('sex', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))->groupBy('sex')->get()->toArray(), function ($carry, $data) {
            $carry[$data['sex']] = $data['count'];
            return $carry;
        });
        return response()->json($users, 200);
    }
```

Hello thanks for time taking time. Here's what i tried found this code in other controllers. although it's still lacking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
$students = Student::where(function($q) use () {
        $q->where('sex', 'male')->whereRelation('academicLevels', 'name', 'elementary')
        ->withCount(['enrollments' as 'enrollment_male_elementary_count'])
    })->where(function($q) use () {
        $q->where('sex', 'female')->whereRelation('academicLevels', 'name', 'elementary')
        ->withCount(['enrollments' as 'enrollment_female_elementary_count'])
    })->where(function($q) use () {
        $q->where('sex', 'male')->whereRelation('academicLevels', 'name', 'junior')
        ->withCount(['enrollments' as 'enrollment_male_junior_count'])
    })->where(function($q) use () {
        $q->where('sex', 'female')->whereRelation('academicLevels', 'name', 'junior')
        ->withcount(['enrollments' as 'enrollment_female_junior_count'])
    })->where(function($q) use () {
        $q->where('sex', 'male')->whereRelation('academicLevels', 'name', 'senior')
        ->withCount(['enrollments' as 'enrollment_male_senior_count'])
    })->where(function($q) use () {
        $q->where('sex', 'female')->whereRelation('academicLevels', 'name', 'senior')
        ->withCount(['enrollments' as 'enrollment_female_senior_count'])
    })
->get();
```

Comment: Hello bro thanks for the answer. Although not sure if this will work for me. I have different academic level table structure.

Comment: Then you have to share your table structure with us. How am I supposed to know? I shared answer with coding standarts.

Comment: Updated my post bro. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can check edited answer

Comment: Have tried the code bro but it seems vscode is detecting formatting issues.

Comment: "syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)"